# hex string's size is being doubled when converted from binary in python3

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, binary, hex

im encrypting message using rsa when i convert the 256 length cipher text to binary using:

```
binary_cipher = str(bin(int.from_bytes(cipher_text,byteorder='big'))[2:].zfill(2048))
```

i get 2048 sized binary string. when i try to convert this binary back to a cipher text using:

```
encrypted_message = hex(int(binary_cipher,2)).lstrip('0x')
```

i get a 512 sized cipher text and thus the rsa decryption isnt accepting it because its not the excpected key size (as i understood)

so long story short why my cipher _text's length is getting increased to 512 when i convert it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cipher_text = bytes("PREM")

binary_cipher = str(bin(int.from_bytes(cipher_text,byteorder='big'))[2:].zfill(2048))

encrypted_message = hex(int(binary_cipher,2)).lstrip('0x')

print(cipher_text)
print(binary_cipher)
print(encrypted_message)
```

Here I get "5052454d" which is "PREM" in Hex ASCII.

**Working Correctly because Hex is 2 Digits Per ASCII Character.**

256 Characters are getting converted to 512 Hex Digits.

To get the ASCII back , try this :

```
B=bytearray.fromhex(encrypted_message)
B.decode()
```

Here I get "PREM"

Comment: it worked! by im still confused how :D

Comment: ASCII Character `P` is CODE 80 which is hex 50 , that is the output given by `hex()` which makes every ASCII Character become 2 Hex DIGITS